# Create a vocabulary notebook [Vim]

Tags: vim

I want to use vim to read foreign texts and collect vocabularies quickly. **Simply by firing a hotkey, the current word (vocab) and sentence (usage) should be piped to my notebook.** This will be done by a vim script (should be simple).

```
# New words (2019-12-07)

word: "Nullstellensatz"
usage: "A general solution of the ideal membership problem provides an effective Nullstellensatz, at least for the weak form."
time: 2019-12-07T22:19:02-04:00
source: /home/username/Hilbert's-Nullstellensatz.md

word: "disponibles"
usage: "Ces outils sont disponibles pour toute forme de consultation, privée ou publique."
time: 2019-12-07T22:21:49-04:00
source: /home/username/CONFIANCE-DANS-LES-PLATEFORMES.md
```

So far, I have figured out how to select word and sentence by `viw` and `vis` in normal mode, and to pipe selected text to an external file by `:'<,'>w!cat >> notebook.md`.

#### remaining problems

1. I have successfully piped the words and sentences to a file, but they stay in the same line. How can I insert a `\n`, `word:` and `usage:` using vim commands?
2. How to get the current time, and pipe that into my target file?
3. How to read the current file name, and pipe that into my target file?

Answer (score 2):

It is way nicer using `redir` than `:w!cat` (`:help :redir`).

```
function! GrabWord()
  normal mz"zyiw"yyis`z
  redir >> /path/to/notebook.md     " CHANGE PATH
  echo 'word: ' . json_encode(@z)
  echo 'usage: ' . json_encode(@y)
  echo 'time: ' . strftime('%FT%T%z')
  echo 'source: ' . json_encode(expand('%:p'))
  echo ''
  redir END
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> Q :silent call GrabWord()<CR>
```

I threw in a `json_encode` so strings including backslashes or double quotes would not break.